# Make webpack use .eslintrc.json in ejected CRA (recent)

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, react-scripts, eslintrc

You find multiple suggestions on how to do it, but all seem outdated or I am missing something else.

We want the webpackDevServer (`npm start`) to log the same errors and warnings as `npx eslint src/` does. We have an `.eslintrc.json` in the root of our project. So we need webpack to pick it up. When I added an `.eslintrc.json` in an unejected CRA project, it seemed to pick it up:

[image]

Not so in the ejected one though. It always looks like this:

[image]

I tried

- adding `EXTEND_ESLINT=true` to npm start in the `package.json`
- pasting the same config as defined in the `.eslintrc.json` in `new ESLintPlugin({baseConfig: ...})` in the `config/webpack.config.js`
- various combinations of commenting out or changing options in the `new ESLintPlugin` in the `config/webpack.config.js`
- putting the `.eslintrc.json` in `/src`, `/config`, etc.
- probably something else and different combinations of the above. Of course I searched the whole internet within 2 hours of tryint to solve this.
- [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70055833/different-eslint-results-when-building-react-app) covers the underlying problem, but doesn't have a solution for what we want to do, as it suggests to

  - either disable linting through webpack completely
  - or overwriting the CRA esLintConfig just like in the current documentation of CRA: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#extending-or-replacing-the-default-eslint-config. It is not explicitely stated where to change it, but the only place where I find a "esLintConfig" object is in the package.json, and putting the rules from our .eslintrc.json there didn't do the trick either.

***So basically there is no documentation on how to achieve it. My hope that someone out there also recently had to deal with this and found a solution? Would be awesome, if you could share it then!***

(Seems like the ejected version of create-react-app's result is a bit broken at the moment. Using .env files throws errors in the react-scripts as well at the momemt, but that's another story.)

Comment: Tried `useEslintrc` in webpack.config file?